# What's the most performatic way to import components and modules in Angular?

Tags: angular, architecture, angular-material2

I've been working in a personal Angular project, using Angular Material as a component library. After a lot of research about project structure, modules and reusable components, I still have a few questions I can't answer about project performance:

Take Angular Material library for instance: some people advocate creating a MaterialModule with all the used modules inside, importing it in AppModule, but wouldn't it be more performatic to import only the few modules I use inside the main components, as the rest will only be usen in lazy loaded modules?

Also, with shared components...is it better to create something like a SharedComponentsModule to declare and export them all, or should each component have its own module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> some people advocate creating a MaterialModule with all the used modules inside

Yes, this is useful for organization. Performance wise, it doesn't make a difference or is minimal, thanks to WebPack

This is not the same as importing everything from Material, which could have a much larger performance impact especially with dozens of libraries.

So don't:

```
import { * } from '@angular/material';
```

in your app.module file.

The point is to avoid an app.module file that is hundreds or thousands of lines long. It would be a pain to read for humans.

Comment: So the idea is to create a module with material modules I use, adding one each time I need a new one, and importing this module in AppModule?

Comment: That is correct. I will usually combine them if they seem like very small usages, but if I get to where it doesn't fit on one page I'll start splitting them out.

Answer (score 0):

Ref: [Getting started with Angular Material](https://robferguson.org/blog/2018/11/05/getting-started-with-angular-material/)

> Step 4: Import the Angular Material component modules

I'm not sure which components I will require so I created a 'wrapper' module that imports (and exports) the complete set of Angular Material component modules.

[angular-material.module.ts](https://github.com/Robinyo/serendipity/blob/master/src/app/shared/angular-material.module.ts):

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { LayoutModule } from '@angular/cdk/layout';

//
// Form Controls
//

import { MatAutocompleteModule } from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatRadioModule } from '@angular/material/radio';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatSliderModule } from '@angular/material/slider';
import { MatSlideToggleModule } from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';

...
```

Comment: If there is code behind the link, add it here. Otherwise, this looks like a comment